# Adding values to array from the Multiautocomplete in android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, multiautocompletetextview

How can i use MultiAutoCompleteTextView to get multiple entries from the user, So that each entries are added to individual Strings and every single Strings should be stored in string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@William Willi

Check below

You will need to use `split()` method since we are using `CommaTokenizer()` for our `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`

so your layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="iifl.animesh.cuser.progressbarexample.MainActivity">

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/multitoken"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/multitoken"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

In your mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private MultiAutoCompleteTextView multiAutoCompleteTextView;

    // your array for the autocomplete

    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
            "India","Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain","USA","China"
    };

    private Button mbutton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        multiAutoCompleteTextView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multitoken);
        mbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        // setting listener for button
        mbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //setting adapter for multiAutoCompleteTextView
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String text = multiAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();

        if(text != null && text.length() >0) {
            text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
        String countries[] = text.split(",");  // countries array will have all the countries entered in multiAutoCompleteTextView

        for(String s : countries) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Countries are = "+s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
        else {
           Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

    }
}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: That perfectly helped me thank you . can you tell me how to insert this values of array into Mysql database in one by one manner. eg:  Like  if user enters "India" first and "Italy" second then MySql entries must be with India in first row then Italy in next row.

Comment: @WilliamWilli mysql meaning on the remote server or your talking about local database that is sql Lite

Comment: Remote Server ,if u have code please share it with me. thank u

Comment: @WilliamWilli sorry dude dont have the code as exactly as you want but you can simple do it with AsyncTask concept of android. Please check online you will get lot of good examples of AsyncTask where you can send data to remote server from android app